# Select columns, skip if column not exist

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I want to make a subset of my data, by selecting columns, like below:

```
select(df, col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

But sometimes I have a slightly different data set, with only col1, col2 and col4.

**How can I use select(), and If a column doesn't exist, it just continues without giving an error?**

So it would give a dataset with col1, col2 and col4 (and skip col3). If I just run the above select() line, I get this error:

```
Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object 'col3' not found
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
df[, names(df) %in% c('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4')]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `one_of()` [select helper](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/select_helpers.html) from dplyr and pass the column names as strings. It will just issue a warning for columns that don't exist.

```r
library(dplyr)

select(mtcars, one_of(c("mpg", "disp", "foo")))

#> Warning: Unknown variables: `foo`

#>                      mpg  disp
#> Mazda RX4           21.0 160.0
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 160.0
#> Datsun 710          22.8 108.0
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4 258.0
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7 360.0
```

Comment: The name of the function has changed to: `any_of()`. https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/all_of.html